# How to calculate the Gaussian Filter kernel

Tags: filter, kernel, gaussian

I am working on image processing project.In that I need to implement Gaussian filter.How to calculate the 3x3, 5x5,7x7 kernels? Please help me.

http://s14.postimg.org/rwpyq8k5d/image.jpg

Comment: how can calculate the val of matrix from gaussian formula

Answer (score 0):

The code below illustrate how to calculate the Gaussian kernel with any filter size and Gaussian weighted parameter.

```
enter code here public static double[,] CalculateGaussianKernel(int length, double weight)
    {
       // define an array of two dimensions based on the length value that pass it by the user from the text box.
        double[,] Kernel = new double[length, length];
        double sumTotal = 0;

        int kernelRadius = length / 2;
        double distance = 0;

        double calculatedEuler = 1.0 / (2.0 * Math.PI * Math.Pow(weight, 2)); // Gaussian Function first part

        for (int filterY = -kernelRadius; filterY <= kernelRadius; filterY++)
        {
            for (int filterX = -kernelRadius; filterX <= kernelRadius; filterX++)
            {
                distance = ((filterX * filterX) + (filterY * filterY)) /(2 * (weight * weight)); // Gaussian Function Second part

                Kernel[filterY + kernelRadius,filterX + kernelRadius] = calculatedEuler * Math.Exp(-distance);

                sumTotal += Kernel[filterY + kernelRadius, filterX + kernelRadius];
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
            {
                Kernel[y, x] = Kernel[y, x] *
                               (1.0 / sumTotal);
            }
        }

        return Kernel;
    }
```